# How to correctly (re)pack omni.ja in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I try to edit some files in `<firefox_dir>/browser/omni.ja`. So I unpacked the archive, did the changes and used

```
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
```

command to repack the archive as suggested in [About omni.ja](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29). However it seems that recommended command doesn't work since Firefox refuses to start:

```
$ ./firefox --no-remote -P altprofile
1439747229638   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on adbhelper@mozilla.org
1439747229824   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229825   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229825   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229825   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229826   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229826   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229826   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229826   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
1439747229909   addons.repository   WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
```

**How to pack `omni.ja` correctly?**

Firefox version: 43.0a1 (2015-08-16)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [latest documentation I can find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar)) at the time of writing this (14/07/2021), the correct way to re-pack the `omni.ja` file is

```sh
zip -0DXqr omni.ja <file(s)/dir(s) to pack>
```

For convenience, you might want to unpack it this way so that all the files go in one sub directory:

```sh
unzip omni.jar -d <target directory>
```

Answer (score -2):

Put zip.exe in the same folder where omni.ja extracted
Use this command to pack everything except zip.exe

```
zip -qr9XD omni.ja * -x "zip.exe"
```

Comment: Do an [edit]. Figure out which answer you want to go with. And delete the other one.

Comment: This seems to be solving a different problem (finding zip.exe).  How will it alter the zip file produced such that Firefox will work?